# How to use a txt file in .map() function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dictionary and using it in .map() function in Pandas, in the same code file.
However, I want to store the dictionary in different txt file, and then call it in .map() function of the code. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Code:

```
Hotels_Region = {"La Pizzeria" : "Italy",
"Domino's" : "Germany",
"Pizza Hut" : "Austria"}

df['country'] = df.store.map(Hotels_Region)
```

I want to store below code in different file:

```
Hotels_Region = {"La Pizzeria" : "Italy",
"Domino's" : "Germany",
"Pizza Hut" : "Austria"}
```

and then call it in

```
df['country'] = df.store.map(Hotels_Region)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Json

```
import json
#SAVE
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(Hotels_Region, outfile)

#LOAD
with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

data

{'La Pizzeria': 'Italy', "Domino's": 'Germany', 'Pizza Hut': 'Austria'}
```

It will work in the map function

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'store':['La Pizzeria']})
df.store.map(data)

0    Italy
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have almost a 400 MB file, dictionary

Comment: And why that's a problem?